# Sorting arrays with reference to a sorted array

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have a reference array which contains all possible elements and is sorted in custom order different than alphanumeric sorting. For example,

```
@ref_array = ('one','two','three','four','five','six');
```

Now all input arrays need to be sorted based on order of reference array. Input array will always be subset of reference array.

```
@in1 = ('three','one','five');  # Input
@out1 = ('one','three','five'); # Desired Output

@in2 = ('six','five','four','three','two','one'); # Input
@out2 = ('one','two','three','four','five','six') # Desired Output
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
my %h = map { $ref_array[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#ref_array;

my @out1 = @ref_array[ sort { $a <=> $b } @h{@in1} ];
my @out2 = @ref_array[ sort { $a <=> $b } @h{@in2} ];
```

`%h` holds key => val pairs like `one` => `0`, `two` => `1`, etc.

`@h{@in1}` is `2,0,4` hash slice which gets sorted, and array slice `@ref_array[0,2,4]` is `one, three, five`

Comment: nice! this is far more elegant than my solution. (Although *please* start explaining your answers!)

Comment: @amon I'll write explanation if OP asks for it, as I'm slow writer and lacking in eloquence

Comment: @amon btw, in ruby you can skip `{ $a <=> $b }` part, is there some module in perl with similar functionality?

Comment: Due to the (lack of) type system in Perl, it requires two sets of comparision operators: `eq` vs. `==`, `cmp` vs `<=>`. Ruby and Perl6 do not have this problem, and can provide generic comparision. In Perl5 string sorting is a sensible default. But you are free to define your own like `sub numsort { sort { $a <=> $b } @_ }`

Comment: To @amon's first point, you could always write an explanation *after* posting your code. Remember that the answers on SO are not just for the OP, but also for anybody else who lands on this page in the future. Having said that, very nice solution.

Comment: Is this meant to be: `my @out1 = @ref_array[ sort { $a <=> $b } @h{@in1} ];` ?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot1 there is some explanation now

Comment: @amon it would be great to have native `numsort` or in some core module

Comment: @amon Thanks for neat solution. That triggered me a more compact solution. `my @out1 = sort { $h{$a} <=> $h{$b} } @in1;`. It's just that I usully get confused among $,@,{,[...

Comment: @JKShah All the credit to mpapec! Your code may *look* shorter, but it is less efficient, as you use much more expensive hash accesses. In contrast, mpapec’s code looks quite optimized. Don't get confused; instead learn to understand what they mean! The [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut) is a good place to start.

Comment: Oops I wanted to thank both of you @mpapec. Oh now it comes to compact v/s efficient code, need to learn. Sure will try to catch it up, thanks for link.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't that complicated.

**Step 1**, we need a mapping from your values to some key that Perl can sort, e.g. numbers. We can use the indices of the elements in your custom collation array, like:

```
my %custom_value = map { $ref_array[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#ref_array;
```

**Step 2**, we do a *Schwartzian Transform* on your input with one of the above values as key:

```
my @out =
  map  { $_->[1] }
  sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
  map  {[ $custom_value{$_} => $_ ]}
       @in;
```

Answer (score 1):

For sorting using a small-integer key, radix sort is usually the faster solution with O(N) complexity:

```
use Sort::Key::Radix qw(ukeysort);

my @ref = ('one','two','three','four','five','six');
my %ref = map { $ref[$_] => $_ } 0..$#ref;

my @out = ukeysort { $ref{$_} } @in;
```

Or you can also use a cheap O(N) counting sort:

```
my %ref;
$ref{$_}++ for @in;
no warnings 'uninitialized';
my @out = map { ($_) x $ref{$_} } @ref;
```

Comment: In the second code block you probably want to assign to `@out` instead `$out`, and maybe wrap the last line in `no warnings "uninitialized"`.

Answer (score 0):

All presented solutions shows sorting with `O(NlogN)` time complexity. There is a way how to do it without actual sorting so in `O(N)` time complexity.

```
sub custom_usort {
    my %h;
    @h{@_} = ();
    grep exists $h{$_}, ('one','two','three','four','five','six');
}
```

**Edit**:

If there can be multiple values in input, there is this solution:

```
sub custom_sort {
    my %h;
    $h{$_}++ for @_;
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    map {($_) x $h{$_}} ('one','two','three','four','five','six');
}
```

Comment: that solution fails when `@in` has repeated elements

Comment: @salva there is not such example in the question.